# Laravel request validation on array of items

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-6, laravel-validation

I do have a form request with

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'order_num'         => ['required', 'date'],
        'order_date'        => ['nullable'],
        'items.*.item_code' => ['required'],
        'items.*.item_id'   => ['required','exists:'. app('db-connection') .'.items,id']
    ];
}
```

*I need to validate whether the item code is unique. item[] is an update query, i need to check, whether item[][item_code] is unique, ignoring the item[][id].*

Thanks in advance for any valuable comments.

Comment: You can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59198620/7498116

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        $requestedItem = $this->request->get('items');


        if (!$requestedItem['item_code']) {
            return  ['items.*.item_code' => 'required'];
        }
        $item = YourModelName::where('item_code', $requestedItem['item_code'])->get();

        $rules = [
            'order_num'         => ['required', 'date'],
            'order_date'        => ['nullable'],
        ];

        if ($item) {
            $rules['items.*.item_id'] = ['required', 'exists:items,id'];
        } else {
            $rules['items.*.item_id'] = ['nullable'];
        }

        return $rules;
```