# How to access nested item in Rule::requiredIf() validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate an array inside a custom Request. The rule evaluates to required if two conditions are met:

1. attribute3 is `true`
2. another column from the same array is `true`

Here's what I'm doing:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'attribute1' => 'required',
        'attribute2' => 'required',
        'attribute3' => 'required',
        ...
        'attribute10.*.column3' => Rule::requiredIf(fn() => $this->attribute3), // <- array
        'attribute10.*.column4' => Rule::requiredIf(fn() => $this->attribute3), // <- array
        'attribute10.*.column5' => Rule::requiredIf(fn() => $this->attribute3), // <- array
    ];
}
```

What I really need is this:

```
'attribute10.*.column4' => Rule::requiredIf(fn($item <- magically hint this currently looped item) => $this->attribute3 && $item->column2 <- so I can use it like this), // <- array
```

Comment: Can you share a example of the incoming request? You can do `Log::debug($this->all());`  in the rules function of the FormRequest just before the return, then check the laravel logs to see what is arriving in the request.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ - I'd rather not share because it's company's privacy and the code is not open source. But the information is the same - I receive an array and when checked against a rule I simply want to have access to it's current item.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer assuming the request structure. Maybe you'll have to adapt it, but there you have an idea

Comment: A while ago I answered another question, which it's not the same, but you can play with the idea adapting it to your requirements https://stackoverflow.com/a/59198620/7498116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the incoming request has a structure like the following:

```
[
    'attribute1' => 1,
    'attribute2' => 0,
    'attribute3' => 1,
    'attribute10' => [
        [
            'column1' => 1,
            'column2' => 1,
            'column3' => 0,
        ],
        [
            'column1' => 0,
            'column2' => 1,
            'column3' => 0,
        ],
    ],
]
```

You can set the rules array to a variable, and then loop over the `attribute10` field array elements and merge each rule on the rules variable. Then you'll have access to the other elements on the nested array.
Ie:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'attribute1' => 'required',
        'attribute2' => 'required',
        'attribute3' => 'required',
    ];
    foreach($this->attribute10 as $key => $item) {
        array_merge($rules, [
            'attribute10.'.$key.'.column2' => Rule::requiredIf($this->attribute3 && $item['column1']),
            'attribute10.'.$key.'.column3' => Rule::requiredIf($this->attribute3 && $item['column2']),
            //...
        ]);
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `foreach` [validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#accessing-nested-array-data).
here is an example from documents:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'companies.*.id' => Rule::forEach(function ($value, $attribute) {
        return [
            Rule::exists(Company::class, 'id'),
            new HasPermission('manage-company', $value),
        ];
    }),
]);
```